# Cyborg-human anime with political themes

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was an anime I recall watching around 2012-2014 on animax (India). I don't have a good recollection but here are fragments of the scenes I remember:

1. Scientist guy (maybe a government employee) is the main character
2. Cyborg-like humans, which people can hire (or something)
3. A scene where the scientist guy/government employee goes shopping with his cyborg assistant (very cute scene) where she tries on new clothes by someone (I can't recollect if it was the scientist) who clicks buttons on an interface. The button would cause the clothes of the cyborg to change.
4. There is a developing romance between the protagonist and the robot assistant
5. A scene where the scientist gets ambushed by some people and then his cyborg assistant goes into a red color mode and starts wrecking them
6. Some cgi-ish scenes? ( I think?)

The ambient society was quite advanced and seemed so that the anime was a bit political. It had a good soundtrack as well.

Comment: Was it a movie or a series?

Comment: I am not sure @fez

Comment: What colour was the female cyborg's hair?

Comment: I think black.. I think it changed though @LogicDictates

Comment: @A plate of momos - Are you the same user who posted this question? If so, please attempt to merge your current account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). I'm not certain if it'll work, since the account used to post this question seems to have been deleted, but give it a try. If it does work, it'll enable you to edit the question yourself, rather than submitting edits for other users to approve or reject. It'll also enable you to leave comments here, like this one.

Comment: @A plate of momos - If you _aren't_ the same user who posted this question, you should consider posting a new question of your own, rather than attempting to edit this one. The fact that this sounds like it's describing the same anime you're looking for doesn't guarantee that it is the same. And even if it is the same, we'll never know that for sure, because neither you nor I can confirm what someone neither of us knows was looking for. If you ask your own story-ID question though, then that makes _you_ the ultimate authority on what the correct answer is.

Comment: This barely reminds me of Armitage III (1995) which I never watched.

Comment: No chance this could be an early version of Alita: Battle Angel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anime is Animax-Lamb (I was the OP). Here's the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaMB). Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vL_GSeJZmE) on YT having the scene I was talking about.

> LaMB takes place in the distant future on a desert planet called Cerra. The story features a prison system, in which prisoners are sealed in personal containment systems known as "laminated suits" and used for labor. Prisoners go through a "Lamination" process, where they are fitted with cybernetic, laminated skin-tight suits. In these suits, they can move around and completed work assignments that cannot be done by machine or robots. Law-abiding citizens are protected, while the criminals become members of society in a futuristic prison system. This process ensures that convicted criminals remain productive members in a system of virtual slavery. The story encompasses the dichotomy between the theory and practice of a futuristic society's justice system.
>
> The lamination process and system of virtual slavery has made both jails and the death penalty obsolete in a world where human ingenuity, creativity, and labor continue to be precious commodities that cannot be replaced by robots or any form of artificial intelligence. The system also sparks off philosophical debates among citizens presenting pros and cons of the ethical feasibility of "Lamination".
>
> The story follows protagonists Sara Integra and Jack Griswold's struggle against Cerra's system of imprisonment. Major Sara Integra is a former weapons specialist in bio-weapons division. While she was on a military assignment, innocent lives were lost during an experiment gone wrong. She was convicted of manslaughter and sentenced to 200 years encased in a laminated suit. Sara forever became known as Eve, or Eve1135.
>
> When she became a LaMB, Eve was assigned a Shepherd. Shepherds control the actions and movement of the LaMBs. Included among the laws of society are that LaMBs must only act upon instructions of their Shepherds. While LaMBs can hear others, they cannot speak, nor can they touch another human being unless ordered by their Shepherd. Dr. Jack Griswold was assigned to be Eve's Shepherd.
>
> Griswold is a scientist from another planet, specializing in advanced botanical engineering. He has been assigned the task to restore vegetation to the dry, desert planet. Among Griswold's superiors is Keiko Suzuki, Chief Scientific Advisor specializing in biophysics, and Sara Integra's niece. She has been deeply affected by the death of her parents, and her aunt's imprisonment, and lamination and has made revenge her ultimate goal in life.
>
> Griswold tends to display workaholic traits, presumably in order to forget the recent loss of his wife. His curiosity and soul-searching thirst to understand the complexities of the universe drives his research. He tends to spend more time in the lab than anywhere else and his intense focus on his research makes him appear awkward when in comes to social interaction. Griswold inadvertently gets pulled into the politics and ethics behind the system of "Lamination", as well as a romance with Eve.
>
> Keiko's anti-LaMB organization and conspiracy is discovered, and she is put into a lamb suit. Due to recent developments in technology her suit is part plant possibly. She goes on a rampage and tries to destroy Eve1135, but she is immobilized by touching Griswold while she attacked him. She loses her balance and falls off the building. Eve1135 is eventually released from prison (possibly hundreds of years later) and she is just Sara Integra and she kisses Griswold after they put flowers on his wife's grave.

Comment: I did send a req to them. Idk if it'll be of effect tho @LogicDictates

Comment: Cool. Thank you.